# How fast do you take damage when you're outside the circle?

Tags: apex-legends

I feel like the impending orange zone of doom deals more damage to me later in the game than it does earlier, but I was a little too panicked to actually do any of the math.

How much damage does the orange area do exactly?

Comment: if it follows most BR games, it should do significantly more damage later on in the game. however i havent gotten stuck in it yet to tell you the exact rates, and it may depend on distance to the inner circle

Comment: Adding to what @Dragonrage stated, it does indeed do more damage the closer you are to the inner circle. I had this experience today at the beginning of my game and towards the end.

Comment: Not sure of the exact rate, but each round it gets worse. The first one is really easy to combat, and anything past round 3 is flat out death.

Answer (score 5):

There is a chart for this available on this website [here](https://www.rockpapershotgun.com/2019/02/20/apex-legends-ring-circle-sizes-ring-damage-stats-for-each-round/) with more details, but it works like most battle royale games, having each round increase the damage taken per tick outside the ring, along with decreasing the time it takes between each round as the rounds progress. The amount of damage per tick for each round (there being 8 rounds) works like this:

| Rounds | Damage Per Tick |
| --- | --- |
| Round 1 | 1 Damage |
| Round 2 | 2 Damage |
| Round 3 | 5 Damage |
| Round 4 | 5 Damage |
| Round 5 | 10 Damage |
| Round 6 | 10 Damage |
| Round 7 | 10 Damage |
| Round 8 | 10 Damage |

I hope this helps you get a better idea of how much time and meds it will take for you to get from one ring to the other!